# How to put variables into PhantomJS generated HTML headers for PDF conversion?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I have a **huge** issue here. I want to auto-generate PDFs files from HTML templates with custom headers and footers, using express.js, phantomjs and EJS.

I don't have any problems putting any "hardcoded" HTML strings in PhantomJS generated headers of footers (they work):

```
footer: {
    height: "3cm",
    contents: ph.callback(function(pageNum, numPages) {
        return "<div style='padding: .2em; font-size: 10pt;border-top: 1px solid #ccc; color: #999;'> FOOTER <span style='float:right'> Página " + pageNum + " / " + numPages + "</span></div>";
    })
```

But, whenever I try to customize it programmatically:

```
var pdfHeader = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(path.join('server/components/mail/html-templates/pdf-header.html'), 'utf8'));
    pdfHeader = pdfHeader({info: info});

    header: {
        height: "3cm",
        contents: ph.callback(function(pageNum, numPages) {
            if (pageNum == numPages) {
                return "";
            }
            return pdfHeader;
        })
    },
```

It fails and gives me this message:

> phantom stdout: SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

How can I put into the header a custom HTML code with some custom data?

Answer (score 2):

So there are a couple of things with the phatomjs contents callback.

1. The function in `ph.callback` has its own context. So it can't see variables outside of its own scope. See https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/issues/224.
   The example that @zgotts provided in the Git issue worked for me.

   ```
   var headerHtml = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(path.join('server/components/mail/html-templates/pdf-header.html'), 'utf8'));
   var createHeader = function(html) {
           return function (pageNum, numPages) {
               //console.log(html);
               console.log('Header set!');
               return '%HTML%';
           }.toString().replace(/%HTML%/, html);
       };

       renderSession.createPage()
           .then(function(_page) {
               page = _page;
               var file = 'file.pdf';

               page.property('paperSize', {
                   format: 'Letter',
                   header: {
                       height: "3.75cm",
                       contents: renderSession.callback(createHeader(headerHtml))
                   }
               })
           });
   ```
2. The second issue that I found was that it wouldn't work if there were line breaks in the ejs file. As a note also, styles don't apply so you will have to add styling inline if there is any.